# Symbolic links and the file_scan_directory() warning

Tags: 7, navigation

I wanted to use the following symbolic link in my root directory:

```
$ ln -s /data1/public/cases/ DownloadData
```

Such that when users go to www.example.com/~user/DownloadData/file they are rerouted to /data1/public/cases/file on the server.

When I did this I can verify that the symbolic link will work by using `ls -l` and clicking on the link.

After applying the symbolic link I get a page with MANY warnings from Drupal.  The warnings show up in the Views UI, Modules UI, and i'm sure more places.

Below are all the warnings.  Notice how it is trying to go into is a kind of combination of the symbolic link and the actual path.  I'm very new to Drupal so please be patient with me :).  Thank you ahead of time.

```
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/cases/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(.//DownloadData/public/Indices/016): failed to open dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2070 of /data1/home/spaceweather/htdocs/sw_test/includes/file.inc).
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just resorted to suppressing the errors for now.  My server admin showed me that it is possible with the .htaccess file to [suppress php errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

The line of code that was added to .htaccess  looks like:

```
# Don't allow PHP warnings to be displayed in Drupal.
php_value error_reporting 6135
```

If anyone finds a real solution please assist.  That darn file_scan_dir() is having a hell of a time with that symbolic link I placed in my root directory.  The time to load several of the admin pages is much longer than it was before this warning appeared and i started using that symbolic link.